# Error in model.frame.default with csv and boxplot2

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I'm new to r, and I'm stuck.

I have a data frame, which I read into r from a csv:

```
    site depth      co2        n2o        ch4
1 ot aue     0 408.7412  2.0432975  11.393448
2 ot aue     0 325.8365 -0.4539224  -2.222266
3 ot aue     0 237.4456  0.6853362 -13.105958
```

which I then subset by "site" (there are five different sites):

```
OTA<-subset(data, site=="ot aue")
```

and I wanted to change the units of the greenhouse gases, and save those values in new columns, which I did here:

```
data$co2mol<-NA
data$co2mol=((data$co2/3600)/12)*1000
data$n2omol=NA
data$n2omol<-((data$n2o/3600)/14)*1000000
data$ch4mol=NA
data$ch4mol<-((data$ch4/3600)/12)*1000
```

I confirmed the changes with:

```
> names(data)
[1] "site"   "depth"  "co2"    "n2o"    "ch4"    "co2mol" "n2omol" "ch4mol"
```

and

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   71 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ site  : chr  "ot aue" "ot aue" "ot aue" "ot aue" ...
 $ depth : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ co2   : num  409 326 237 294 557 ...
 $ n2o   : num  2.043 -0.454 0.685 2.084 5.911 ...
 $ ch4   : num  11.39 -2.22 -13.11 3.66 -11.15 ...
 $ co2mol: num  9.46 7.54 5.5 6.82 12.89 ...
 $ n2omol: num  47.3 -10.5 15.9 48.2 136.8 ...
 $ ch4mol: num  0.2637 -0.0514 -0.3034 0.0847 -0.2582 ...
```

Now, I need to plot the data, using the columns I created with the new units.
This code works with the original columns (co2, n2o, ch4), but not the new columns (co2mol, n2omol, ch4mol).

```
ota_co2mol<-boxplot2(OTA$co2mol~OTA$depth, data=OTA,
                  xlab="Depth in Hole (cm)", 
                  ylab="mol CO2",
                  col = c("tan", "tan2", "tan3", "tan4", "burlywood4"), 
                  main=expression("Ot Aue CO"[2]),
                  top=TRUE,
                  ylim=c(-593,3762))
```

When trying to create the boxplot, I get this error message:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = OTA$co2mol ~ OTA$depth, data =
>   OTA) :    invalid type (NULL) for variable 'OTA$co2mol'

Obviously this is a data.frame/data.table/data format/data reading error, I just don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: All your sample output shows the data being in a variable called `data` but your call to boxplot2 references `OTA`. Did you change something for the question?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that. I subset "data" by site. OTA is "ot aue." 

OTA<-subset(data, site=="ot aue")